# Run python script with opencv from C++

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I'm trying to execute python script from C++,

C++ part:

```
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("print(sys.version)");
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append('/path/to/module')");
pName = PyString_FromString("mymodule");
pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
import_array();
PyArrayObject *np_ret, *np_arg;
pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "process");
PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(pFunc, NULL);
```

python module:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys
import segno


def process():
  n = random.randint(1, 1000);
  qr = segno.make(n)
  mark = np.uint8(np.array(qr.to_pil(scale=2)))*255
  mark = cv2.cvtColor(mark, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
```

When I compile it with opencv `3.2.0` it's working fine, but with `2.4.0` it gives segmentation fault on calling opencv function `cv2.cvtColor(mark, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)`

Is it possible to do so with `2.4.0`? Maybe there is some module initializer such as `import_array()`for numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax is different at 2.4 so modify as following

```
mark = cv2.cvtColor(mark,mark, CV_GRAY2RGB)
```